# Best way to add components dynamically to a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

What is the best way to add components dynamically to your vue app?

Say you have three different components in your app and you want to show each one depending on the value that a data has.

```js
data:() => ({
  tab: 1
})
```

```html
<custom-component-1></custom-component-1> <!-- Show this if tab is 1 -->
<custom-component-2></custom-component-2> <!-- Show this if tab is 2 -->
<custom-component-3></custom-component-3> <!-- Show this if tab is 3 -->
```

I'm gonna go through all the possible ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `v-if` or `v-show`

The first and obvious way is to add `v-if` to your component like this:

```html
<custom-component-1 v-if="tab === 1"></custom-component-1> <!-- Show this if tab is 1 -->
<custom-component-2 v-if="tab === 2"></custom-component-2> <!-- Show this if tab is 2 -->
<custom-component-3 v-if="tab === 3"></custom-component-3> <!-- Show this if tab is 3 -->
```

*You can also use `v-show` if you want to, it's up to you.*

See the difference between `v-show` and `v-if`. [v-show vs v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)

This probably is the easiest way of doing it but not the most efficient.
once your code starts to get more complicated this code is going to be your hell

### Using Vue's dynamic components

The second way of doing this is by using Vue's dynamic components [Link to documention](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Here is our example again with dynamic components:

```js
computed: {
  component: function () {
   return `custom-component-${this.tab}`;
 }
},

data:() => ({
  tab: 1
})
```

And we just need to pass the name of the components:

```html
<component is="component"> 
<!-- instead of -->
<custom-component-number></custom-component-number>
```

```html
 <component :is="component"> </component>
 <button @click="tab++"></button>
```

Using the `computed` and `is` property we can have infinite components dynamically.
This is a nice clean way of doing it. You take the computation part away from your markup and put it in the script for a cleaner and more efficient code

**If you are using this approach make sure to import and initialize the components you want to use in the page or add them in your `main.js` as global components like this:**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Component1 from "~/components/component1.vue";
import Component2 from "~/components/component2.vue";
import Component3 from "~/components/component3.vue";

Vue.component("custom-component-1",Component1);
Vue.component("custom-component-2",Component2);
Vue.component("custom-component-3",Component3);
```

You can also add the components to your page:

```js
import customComponent from "~components/customComponent";
```

```js
export default {
   components : {
     customComponent: "custom-component"
   }
}
```